# Creating a Rails 5 migration for foreign key(s) referencing their own table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I'm writing a little dog database that shows family trees.
I have a postgresql table 'dogs' that has a dog_id, name, weight, etc.
I also want it to have a mother_id and a father_id that stores another dog_id.

First of all, does that even work?
And how would I write that migration in for Rails5?

Or should I have another table 'parentage' that just links dogs to one another?

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with neongrau. You don't need a second table to achieve this. It can be done by making a dynamic self join in your dogs table. You would first declare all the relationships in a single model, and their foreign keys respectively:

**models/dog.rb:**

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mom, class_name: "Dog", foreign_key: "mom_id"
  belongs_to :dad, class_name: "Dog", foreign_key: "dad_id"
  has_many :kids, class_name: "Dog"
end
```

and then you would run a migration referencing mom and dad:

```
class CreateDogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dogs do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :age
      t.references :mom
      t.references :dad
      t.integer :dog_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
end
```

And now we test it out by building our associations manually:

```
   kid = Dog.create(name: "Rover")
    => #<Dog id: 8, name: "Rover"..>

   ma = Dog.create(name: "Susie")
   => #<Dog id: 2, name: "Susie"..>

   pa = Dog.create(name: "Doug")
   => #<Dog id: 8, name: "Doug"..>

kid.mom_id = 2
kid.save

kid.mom
 => #<Dog id: 2, name: "Susie"...>

kid.dad_id = 3
kid.save

kid.dad
 => #<Dog id: 3, name: "Doug"...>


ma.kids << kid
ma.save

ma.kids
 => #<Dog id: 1, name: "Rover"...>

pa.kids << kid 
pa.save

pa.kids
 => #<Dog id: 1, name: "Rover"...>
```

Now you have a dynamic relationship where dogs can have multiple kids, and may belong to a mother and father.

Comment: Happy to disagree with yours too ;)
STI are nice and easy but when you need to iterate through a tree you have a n+2 sql query problem for every level in the ancestry (mom and dad). So with great-great-grandparents you're already at n+2+4+8 sql queries to render a family tree.

Site performance will be non existing.

Comment: Everything can be cached. You can create a method that eager loads the nesting of ids, cache it and have the iterator use that.

Comment: I've tried it MisterCal's way now and it works perfectly fine. I do see neongrau's point about performance and I'll look into the handy ClosureTree stuff for refactoring.
Since it's currently just running locally as a trial, I'm not too worried about performance.

Comment: Good, the base Model dogs with the associated parents are fine though for that. The closure tree you can add a later point which would then act as the cache. That's what all different hierarchy tree solutions (nested-sets, adjacent-lists, closure trees) are for. In the closure tree you would add new root for every single dog and reverse the direction by adding the parents as child-nodes into the tree. Even a parent would then exist multiple times at different levels in that tree so you can read the full ancestral line of any dog in one sql query.

Comment: @neongrau You don't really need anything fancy or denormalized for pulling out a whole tree, PostgreSQL supports `WITH RECURSIVE` queries.

Comment: You can still have proper foreign keys in the database with this approach too. Just declare the foreign keys in the migration *after* the `create_table`.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go for at least a second table.

I'd suggest adding a Pairing or Litter Model and Map your dogs with that as breeders could possibly have the same pairing again.

As hierarchies get problematic in performance real fast with deeper nested data you might consider storing ancestries for each dog in another table or two to be able to retrieve them quick enough for a website.

I'd suggest https://github.com/ClosureTree/closure_tree as it offers the best performance for this scenario (read often, written not so often).